# How do I find all points of an isosceles triangle given the vertex point, base midpoint, and base width?

Tags: algorithm, math, cartesian-coordinates

I'm trying to make a properly-rotated isosceles triangle. I have the following data:

- The `(x, y)` coordinates of the vertex point, *A*
- The `(x, y)` coordinates of the midpoint of the base, *a<sub>m</sub>*
- The width of the base, *a*

And I need to find the coordinates of the other two points, *B* and *C*.
**What is an algorithm for finding these last two points with only the above information?** Searching Google just got me a lot of equations that assume it's pointed directly up, but I need these to be placed *before* a transformation is performed.

[image: An isosceles triangle rotated so that the vertex (labeled with a blue capital A) is in the lower-left and the base (labeled with a red lower-case a) is on the upper-right. The base is bisected by its midpoint (labeled by a green a with a subscript m). The other two points are labeled with a purple capital B and an orange capital C, respectively.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Please let me know where the line lies between having trouble computing numbers in pseudocode and having trouble doing maths, so I know where to put future questions. Also, how my question differs from the other 25k [`math`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find `B` and `C`:

1. find the normalized direction vector `a_mA = (A - a_m)/|A - a_m|`
2. find a vector orthogonal to the vector `a_mA` – let's call it `a_mA'`

   - `a_mA' = (-a_mA.y, a_mA.x)`
3. to find `B`, step `width/2` units in the direction of `a_mA'` and add `a_m`:

   - `B = (width/2)*a_mA' + a_m`
4. to find `C`, step `-width/2` units in the direction of `a_mA'` and add `a_m`:

   - `C = (-width/2)*a_mA' + a_m`

JsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/asq7h2jd/

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer provides a concrete algorithm with an example implementation.

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm! No idea why the downvote, but my up counteracted it :)

Comment: @BenLeggiero Thank you :) I'm glad I could help. If you like the answer please consider accepting it.

Comment: Done and done. Just one thing: I adapted your JS code for my implementation, but I think your answer here uses `a_mA` where it should use `a_mA'` in one or two places, as trying to implement this didn't wield the results I expected.

Comment: @BenLeggiero yes, you're perfectly right – thanks, I've edited the answer (the error was in the computation of `B` and `C`).